# Create a new dataframe with 12 months lag data from an old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df_train as follows:

```
             X1  
01-01-2020 | 1     
01-02-2020 | 2     
01-03-2020 | 3      
01-04-2020 | 4  
01-05-2020 | 5     
01-06-2020 | 6     
01-07-2020 | 7      
01-08-2020 | 8
```

Now I want to build another df with an datetime index

I will get the datetime index as:

```
future_dates = pd.date_range(df_train.index.max(), periods=12, freq='M')
```

I want to get a new df that will get the same month data from the train_df. If the month data does not exist, it will use the mean of ts_train

Desired outcome:

```
               X1  
  01-09-2020 | 36/8     
  01-10-2020 | 36/8     
  01-11-2020 | 36/8      
  01-12-2020 | 36/8 
  01-01-2020 | 1     
  01-02-2020 | 2     
  01-03-2020 | 3      
  01-04-2020 | 4 
  01-05-2021 | 5     
  01-06-2021 | 6     
  01-07-2021 | 7      
  01-08-2021 | 8
```

Comment: Try `fillna()` and pass the mean value after getting the `date_range`

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
df_train.index=pd.to_datetime(df_train.index,dayfirst=True)
future_dates=pd.date_range(df_train.index.max(), periods=12, freq='M')-pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
```

Finally make use of `reindex()`:

```
new_df_train=df_train.reindex(future_dates)
df_train['month']=df_train.index.month
new_df_train['X1']=new_df_train.index.month.map(df_train.set_index('month')['X1'])
new_df_train=new_df_train.fillna(new_df_train['X1'].mean())
```

output of `new_df_train`:

```
            X1
2020-08-01  8.0
2020-09-01  4.5
2020-10-01  4.5
2020-11-01  4.5
2020-12-01  4.5
2021-01-01  1.0
2021-02-01  2.0
2021-03-01  3.0
2021-04-01  4.0
2021-05-01  5.0
2021-06-01  6.0
2021-07-01  7.0
```

Comment: I am not fully understanding the logic here. You are replicating the futures_dates exactly the same way as the dates I have in train_df but i want the furure_dates be the next 12 months after the end of train_df.

Comment: @user2512443 gotcha wait a min letme correct the solution

Comment: thank you. JFYI, I tried the solution with future_dates in the next 12 months and the the current solution gives the same values (only mean).

Comment: @user2512443 updated answer kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thank you. This looks great. The key seems to be the usage of map function.

Comment: @user2512443 `map()` for mapping and `pd.offsets.MonthBegin()` for rounding `pd.date_range()` values to month begin